# Why am I getting Jackson ObjectMapper Parsing Error due to some issues in LinkedHashMap initiation?

Tags: json, jackson

I want to read this JSON using ObjectMapper:

```
{
  "basePath": "/v1",
  "models": {
    "Course":{
      "number": "integer",
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string"
    },
    "Department": {
      "name": "string",
      "code": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I used Jackson ObjectMapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream inputStream = Input.class.getResourceAsStream("/input.json");
Input input = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Input.class);
```

Where Input is:

```
public class Input {

  String basePath;
  Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> models;

  public String getBasePath() {
    return basePath;
  }

  public void setBasePath(String basePath) {
    this.basePath = basePath;
  }

  public Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> getModels() {
    return models;
  }

  public void setModels(Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> models) {
    this.models = models;
  }
}
```

But I am getting JSON Mapping Error.

```
Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provide json structure does not matches with the models map structure. You have two options for it either change in Map or change in json.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> models;
```

If change in json structure like below.

```
{
  "basePath": "/v1",
  "models": {
    "Course":{
      "Details":{
      "number": "integer",
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string"
      }
      }
    }

  }
```

I think better to change in Map thing rather to change the JSON structure.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I changed the map, I made mistake in analyzing the structure and added additional inner map. That worked. However, I am only able to read the first inner model i.e. Course in my case, and not the subsequent ones.

Comment: I will, but before that just wanted to check with you, if you have idea why the next inner objects are not being read by mapper? I'm looking into it anyway!

Comment: it working fine for inner object too. If you need complete working example I can share you.